# Problem in sending Dictionary object(converted JSON file) to template using render in DJANGO

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, key

I am fetching an external json file . Whenever I send the data in dictionary form to html page and reload it, The page doesn't opens instead that html file is downloaded.

My views function:

def index(req):

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.covid19india.org/states_daily.json").read()

output = json.loads(data)

print(output)
 
return render(req,'india.html',{'countries':countries},{'states':output})
```

Comment: You pass the two context variables in a single dictionary, so `return render(req,'india.html',{'countries':countries, 'states':output})`

Comment: Thank you! That works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass *multipe* variables to the template, you do this as entries in the *same* dictionary:

```
def index(req):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'https://api.covid19india.org/states_daily.json'
    ).read()
    output = json.loads(data)
    return render(
        req,
        'india.html',
        {'countries':countries, 'states':output}
    )
```